# Is there any way to use a ftm message tag as title?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm trying to use text as a title but getting it from fmt dynamically.

This is what I tried

1. `<forms:button name="btnUploadSuccess" text=<fmt:message key="SUCCESS_BUTTON_TEXT"/>/>`

2. `<forms:button name="btnUploadSuccess" text="<fmt:message key="SUCCESS_BUTTON_TEXT"/>"/>`

3. `<forms:button name="btnUploadSuccess" text=${<fmt:message key="SUCCESS_BUTTON_TEXT"/>}/>`

If there is any way to do so. Please help.

When I tried these methods I got `javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: ServletException` exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this by creating var for `fmt:message` before.

```
    <fmt:message key="SUCCESS_BUTTON_TEXT" var="SUCCESSBUTTONTEXT"/>
    <forms:button name="btnUploadSuccess" text="${SUCCESSBUTTONTEXT}"/>
```